# Lost between 2 version of PHP running on the same environement

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, mamp

Typing on the **console** gives me :

```
php -v : 5.3.2 PHP 5.3.2 (cli) (built: Oct 13 2010 13:09:53)
mysql.sock : /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

It's the version installed with MAMP (which i've just uninstalled)

If i do a `phpinfo()` **on a browser**

```
PHP Version 5.3.3
/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

**The problem** 
I want to use the PHP 5.3.3 with the `/var/mysql/mysql.sock`  both on the browser and the CLI (otherwise i can't access to my database because there are 2 socket).

How to override the CLI installation please ? (I'm running MAC OSX 10.6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using MAMP are you using port :8888 in your browser. OSX has apache/php installed natively. If you're using MAMP I would assume the CLI version is the OSX version and the browser version (from the MAMP start page) is running as a sperate application.

Comment: You can also try sudo apachectl stop to stop the OSX version and see how your results turn out.

Comment: I've just uninstalled MAMP. The problem is that the MAMP php cli version remains and it's preventing me to connect via mysql via console because it's linking to MAMP's mysql. If i Kill apache, php -v still echoes 5.3.2 and it only kills the version i want to keep.

Comment: Have you upgraded the default PHP install? It is 5.3.2 on OSX 10.6 by default. MAMP comes with 5.3.2 as well.

Comment: yes, i do have upgraded manuall to 5.3.3. But it seems that i failed upgrading the CLI. All i want to to is running PHP CLI from the version i installed and NOT from the MAMP.

Comment: Cool - you'll need to look at your path variable - I'll have to look up the exact settings but basically "php" point to an executable on your system and you'll need to update the path for it

Comment: echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin   ||| my 5.3.3 PHP is stocked under /usr/local/php5-3-3/bin

Comment: Okay - that makes sense then - it need to have in your path variable as well. I did a little searching and you should be able to do this:
http://www.webrelatedstuff.com/articles/mac-server-setup/install-php-5-3-3-on-mac-os-x-/3

read the part related to:
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/php5-3-3/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/php5-3-3/bin/phpize /usr/local/bin/phpize
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/php5-3-3/bin/php-config /usr/local/bin/php-config

Comment: Its just creating links from your old binaries to your new ones - just replace their php5-3-3 path with your /usr/local/php5-3-3/bin